# JQuery: 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' at ajax request - several elements

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have two select elements, A and B: when A's selected option changes, B's options must be updated accordingly. Each element in A implies many elements in B, it's a one-to-many relationship (A contains nations, B should contain cities located in the given nation).

The function `do_ajax` should run the asynchronous request:

```
function do_ajax(elem, mydata, filename)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: filename,
        context: elem,
        data: mydata,
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            elem.innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
```

In order to update B's options I've added a function call in A's `onChange` event. Here is the function that runs when onChange event (of `A`) is triggered:

```
function my_onchange(e) // "e" is element "A"
{
    var sel_B = ... ; // get select element "B"

    // I skipped some code here
    // ...

    var data = {
        'mode': 'filter_city',
        'id_A': e[e.selectedIndex]
    };
    do_ajax(city_sel, data, 'ajax_handler.php');
}
```

}

I've read in [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that `data` can be an array (key value pairs). I get the error if I put:

```
var data = {
        'mode': 'filter_city',
        'id_A': e[e.selectedIndex]
};
```

Instead, I don't get that error if my data is a string:

```
var data = 'mode=filter_city&amp;id_A=' + e[e.selectedIndex];
```

But I need the "array version" of the variable, in my server-side php code.

The `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` is located in the "jquery-1.7.2.min.js" file, which is all compressed, so I couldn't figure out what part of code raised the error.

Is there any setting I can change in my code so that it accepts data as an associative array?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Thanks to the talk with **Sarfraz** we could figure out the solution.

The problem was that I was passing an HTML element instead of its value, which is actually what I wanted to do (in fact in my php code I need that value as a foreign key for querying my `cities` table and filter correct entries).

So, instead of:

```
var data = {
        'mode': 'filter_city',
        'id_A': e[e.selectedIndex]
};
```

it should be:

```
var data = {
        'mode': 'filter_city',
        'id_A': e[e.selectedIndex].value
};
```

**Note:** check Jason Kulatunga's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071290/1175496), it quotes JQuery doc to explain why passing an HTML element was causing troubles.

Comment: exactly what i was doing. Forgot to use .val()

Comment: I was passing the option, of a select html element in a variable. Did not notice it was not plain text but html.

Answer (score 80):

I was getting this error while posting a FormData object because I was not setting up the ajax call correctly.  Setup below fixed my issue.

```
var myformData = new FormData();        
myformData.append('leadid', $("#leadid").val());
myformData.append('date', $(this).val());
myformData.append('time', $(e.target).prev().val());

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: myformData,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: 'include/ajax.php',
    success: function (response) {
        $("#subform").html(response).delay(4000).hide(1); 
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks man. u saved my day and my problem is solved with adding  "processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false," in my ajax body. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,` solved my problem.

Comment: this is the more proper answer. amazing saved my day big time. i was serializing and it was cool and smooth until files got larger....

Comment: Thanks from me too, after 2 hours digging I got the fix from your solution by adding the processData: false in my ajax body.

Answer (score 54):

From the jQuery docs for `processData`:

> **processData** Boolean
>   <sup>Default: true</sup>
>   By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Source:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Looks like you are going to have to use `processData` to send your data to the server, or modify your php script to support querystring encoded parameters.

Comment: This is true. If I could have seen it before it would have pointed me to the actual error in my code. Thanks, I'll add a note in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

> I've read in JQuery docs that data can be an array (key value pairs).
>   I get the error if I put:

This is object not an array:

```
var data = {
        'mode': 'filter_city',
        'id_A': e[e.selectedIndex]
};
```

You probably want:

```
var data = [{
        'mode': 'filter_city',
        'id_A': e[e.selectedIndex]
}];
```

Comment: it doesn't throw that error anymore but it seems that this data is not being passed to my `$_GET` array server-side (`var_export($_GET)` outputs `array (
  'undefined' => 'undefined',
)`)

Comment: @nadirs: Try defining method type in your `$.ajax` handler: `type:'get',`

Comment: @Sarfraz the result is the same. Server-side, `data` keys should be found in GET array, right? Or maybe they're sent via another request method anyway?

Comment: @nadirs: Something like this works `data: {foo:'myfoo', bar:'mybar'}`, there might be some other problem I think.

Comment: @Sarfraz I'm an idiot, I was sending an HTML object `e[e.selectedIndex]` while I should have passed its value `e[e.selectedIndex].value`. After fixing this flaw, object notation works fine.

Comment: thanks for your time. What should I do now? Accept this answer or write my own? I solved the problem thanks to this talk, so it's not untrue that it helped.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue recently, solved by adding `traditional: true,`

Comment: This actually works, I'm assuming for modern browsers only though

Comment: Looks like this did the trick. .. Have no idea why. .. Also has no idea why it stopped to work at first place - everything was ok before!

Answer (score 10):

Please follow the procedure to get rid of this problem:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://your-api-endpoint',
   type: 'post',
   data: new formData(this),
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function(response) {
      console.log(response)
   }
})
```

You have to use processData: false and contentType: false, these two lines. Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same problem and I could correct it as follows.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form_id'));
                                
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Settings/de_acc',
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
})
```

Comment: well done machan

Answer (score 3):

My `illegal invocation` error on `$.getJSON` was caused by passing `undefined` as one of the values for the `data` object.  Fixing that solved the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
function do_ajax(elem, mydata, filename)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: filename,
        context: elem,
        data: mydata,
        **contentType: false,
        processData: false**
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            elem.innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: A [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is more than just a code snippet. It should explain why this answers the initial question and provide links to the relevant documentation, if available.

Comment: Without the two fields `contentType` and `processData`, the error will keep showing. I added the two fields and it worked for me. I think op was trying to indicate the two important fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax does no allow for a JSON object as the data. Using `JSON.stringify()` might solve the issue. Something like this:

```
function do_ajax(elem, mydata, filename)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: filename,
        context: elem,
        data: JSON.stringify(mydata), //Here's the change
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            elem.innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQUERY CHANGES** :
on your JQUERY you need to put this to make your data send as an array

```
JSON.stringify(yourArr);
```

**LARAVEL CHANGES** :
then you need to do this on your LARAVEL controller to get the array correctly (just like a php array) :

```
json_decode($request->theArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
            $.ajax({
                    url:"",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData($('#uploadDatabaseForm')[0]),
                    contentType:false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success:function (msg) {}
                  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
                    url:"",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData($('#uploadDatabaseForm')[0]),
                    contentType:false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success:function (msg) {}
                  });
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful if you include an explanation.