# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, ajax

Since upgrading to jquery 1.9.1, this ajax call, that used to work fine, breaks in chrome.

Error message is: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` .

In firefox, it breaks too, and the error message is: `NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object`

Here is the code. All the functions arguments are of the expected type, so i'm a bit puzzled as to what is happening here.

```
var my_params = {
    'cache': false,
    'data': {
        url: Obj.url,
        section: Obj.section,
        item: Obj.item,
        historyfile: LabHistory.dataFile
    },
    'dataType': 'html',
    'timeout': 3000,
    'url': LabHistory.urlWrite + '?historyfile=' + LabHistory.dataFile
};
/* PROBLEM HAPPENS HERE, AT THE AJAX() CALL. ARGUMENTS ARE
cache=false
    data= {url : 'http://client.dev/projects/project-name/' , section:'projects'
item:'project-name' }
dataType=html
timeout=3000
url=_www/_application/history.write.php 
*/
$.ajax(my_params).done(function()
{
    $.log('history.refresh.write data worked.');
    refreshHistory();
}).fail(function()
{
    $.log('history.refresh.write data failed');
});
```

**EDIT**
Here is the log() function.

```
jQuery.log = function(message)
{
    var mymessage = '';
    if (typeof message === 'array' || typeof message === 'object')
    {
        for (var prop in message)
        {
            if (typeof prop !== 'function')
            {
                mymessage += "\n"+ prop + '=' + message[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mymessage = message;
    }
    if (window.console)
    {
      window.console.log(mymessage);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is `$.log`?  They are probably calling `console.log` incorrectly in the plugin.  For example `console.log.call(null, 'a')` will throw `Illegal invocation`.

Comment: It's a log function that uses console.log if `window.console` is available, otherwise does nothing.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the issue, they might be using `console.log` incorrectly.  Do you have a link to that plugin?

Comment: Just updated the question with the log() function .

Comment: Ok, seems like `$.log` is *not* the issue.

Comment: Probably not the issue,but i noticed something strange... you're passing the historyFile data twice. Once in the data prameter, then again in your url. What kind of data does that variable contain? (string? array? object? blob?)

Comment: Yeah i didn't think so... My testing shows that it happens at the ajax call.

Comment: Do you know which line is throwing the error?

Comment: would be a good idea to highlight (using a comment in your code) on which line does the compiler report your error

Comment: Done. Also added the argument object.

Comment: The error isn't on that line - it'll be somewhere within `$.ajax`

Comment: In your `data` object, those are all strings, yes?  
Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11071367