# Strange error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

UPDATE

The problem was solved, it seems that I was being stupid and forgot to put the .value after referencing the title element.

---

I have been using ajax for a few months now, and have never come across an error like this before.

I am creating an array of formData and passing it over to a php script using ajax like I have done many times before, however I am now getting that strange error.

Could it possibly have something to do with my formData? I can't see how as it isn't any different to how I have done it before.

Any help would be great, thanks!

```
    //This function will add the product and its details to the cart.
    function addToCart(e)
    {
        //alert("CLick");
        calculatePrice();

        //Get the product ID from the URL
        var id = getParameterByName('productID');
        alert(id);
        //Get the title.
        var title = document.getElementById('title');
        //Get the qty.
        var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;         
        //Get the weight.
        var weightList = document.getElementById('weightList');
        var weightText = weightList.options[weightList.selectedIndex].text;
            //alert("Text: " + weightText);
        var weightValue = weightList.options[weightList.selectedIndex].value;
            //alert("Val: " + weightValue);

        formData = {"ID" : id, "SRC": "", "Title" : title, "Qty" : qty, "Weight" : weightText, "Totalprice" : totalPrice, "Singularprice" : weightValue, "Action" : "Add"};
        $.ajax(
                {           
                url: 'manipulateCart.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                success: function(data)
                {       
                    alert("cc");
                    //document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "";
                    //$('#content').append(data);   
                },          
                error: function(xhr,err)
                {       
                    alert("Error: " + xhr + " " + err);
                }

            });

    }
```

Comment: `weightText` and `weightValue` are they coming perfectly.?

Comment: Hi, weightText returns like so: 110g Bag and weightValue returns like so: 3.00. Could it be something to do with the double value type on weightValue?

Answer (score 2):

Missing `.value` in this line

```
 var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
                                              ^^^^^
```

Comment: Ah yes that was the reason, thanks! I must have been rushing that line and forgot to put it. Thanks again, +1!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `title` variable to the formData object. This variable holds the `#title` element, not the value of that element. Add `.value` to `var title = document.getElementById('title');`

Result:

`var title = document.getElementById('title').value;`.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071290/1130234