# Illegal invocation in an AJAX request not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to AJAX calls, one to GET and one to POST. My GET request works fine, but when I call my POST request it throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at jquery.js:9508`. My entire code looks like what follows but the failing part is the `click` function on `$('div#save`) and the successful GET is on `('div#edit')`.

I've checked my backend and it's not even hitting it on the POST. What's the issue?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div#save').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        new_data = {
            first_name: $('input#first_name').val(),
            surname: $('input#surname').val(),
            degree: $('input#degree').val(),
            location: $('input#location').val(),
            availability: $('input#availability'),
            status: $('select#status').val(),
            bio: $('textarea#bio').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/update-freelancer/',
            data: new_data,
            success: function(){
                $('h1#name').text(data['first_name'] + " " + data['surname'].substring(0,1) + ".");
                $('span#degree_text').text(data['degree']);
                $('span#location_text').text(data['location']);
                $('span#availability_text').text(data['availability']);
                $('span#status_text').text(data['status']);
                $('span#bio_text').text(data['bio']);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Oh no!");
            }
        });


    });

    $('div#cancel').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('div.save').hide();
        $('div#edit').show();

        $('h1#name').show();
        $('span#degree_text').show();
        $('span#location_text').show();
        $('span#availability_text').show();
        $('span#status_text').show();
        $('span#bio_text').show();

        $('input#first_name').hide();
        $('input#surname').hide();
        $('input#degree').hide();
        $('input#location').hide();
        $('input#availability').hide();
        $('select#status').hide();
        $('textarea#bio').hide();
    });

    $('div#edit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('div#edit').hide();
        $('div.save').css('display', 'inline-block');

        $('h1#name').hide();
        $('span#degree_text').hide();
        $('span#location_text').hide();
        $('span#availability_text').hide();
        $('span#status_text').hide();
        $('span#bio_text').hide();

        $('input#first_name').show();
        $('input#surname').show();
        $('input#degree').show();
        $('input#location').show();
        $('input#availability').show();
        $('select#status').show();
        $('textarea#bio').show();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/get-freelancer-details/',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data['surname']);
                $('input#first_name').val(data['first_name']);
                $('input#surname').val(data['surname']);
                $('input#degree').val(data['degree']);
                $('input#location').val(data['location']);
                $('input#availability').val(data['availability']);
                $('select#status').val(data['student_type']);
                $('textarea#bio').val(data['bio']);
            }});
        });

});
```

Comment: `availability: $('input#availability'),` did you mean to put  `$('input#availability').val(),`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11071367/712558

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah, that fixed it! Would you like to post it as an answer? Also, how can I debug these issues in future?