# Save time duration of video to database with JQuery ajax returning an error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on saving the video current time and the total video duration using php and jquery ajax.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var by = $('#by').val();
    var inviteId = $('#inviteId').val();
    var currentTime =$('#currentTime').val($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).currentTime);
    var totalTime = $('#totalTime').val($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).duration); 
        $.ajax({
            url     :   '/Scripts/functions/updatevid.php',
            type    :   'POST',
            data    :   {
                         submit : 1,
                         by : by,
                         inviteId : inviteId,
                         currentTime : currentTime,
                         totalTime : totalTime
                        },
            success :   function(result){
                        console.log(result);
            }
        })
},1000);
```

I have the backend code for this already with PHP.
My problem is it is returning an "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" error message in the console.

[image]
How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it give you a line number where the error occurs?

Comment: it points to the jquery library on line 5

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the data properly? It's problem with data sent through ajax. Make sure this part is correct `data    :   {
                         submit : 1,
                         by : by,
                         inviteId : inviteId,
                         currentTime : currentTime,
                         totalTime : totalTime
                        }`. Refer [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071100/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-at-ajax-request-when-data-param)

Comment: yes, I checked it several times.. however, when I inspect element on the textbox containing the total video duration and current time.. there is no value set. I am thinking this is the one causing the error.. but as you can see from the code above I assigned a value to those two textboxes

Comment: If possible can you add the browser console image with the sent data?

Comment: I added the console image.. please check.. also you can see from the console the anonymous function. it is pointing to $.ajax({ .... })

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I already know what is happening.
It seems that the value of the textbox for currentTime and totalTime is not being assigned properly. so I added the .val() for currentTime and totalTime to get the actual value.

below is my fixed code. It is now working as it should.

```
setInterval(function(){
var by = $('#by').val();
var inviteId = $('#inviteId').val();
var currentTime =$('#currentTime').val($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).currentTime);
var totalTime = $('#totalTime').val($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).duration); 
    $.ajax({
        url     :   '/Scripts/functions/updatevid.php',
        type    :   'POST',
        data    :   {
                     submit : 1,
                     by : by,
                     inviteId : inviteId,
                     currentTime : currentTime.val(),
                     totalTime : totalTime.val()
                    },
        success :   function(result){
                    console.log(result);
        }
    })
},1000);
```

Thanks guys.