# jQuery $.ajax and jQuery UI dialog: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to send an AJAX request when I click a jQuery UI dialog `Save` button and this is how I am doing it:

```
$(function () {
    var comment_dlg = $('#add_comment_dialog');
    var quote_id = $('#comment_quote_id');

    $('#order_push').click(function () {
        quote_id.val($(this).data('id'));
        comment_dlg.dialog('open');
    });

    comment_dlg.dialog({
        title: "Write a comment",
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Save': function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: Routing.generate('push_order_xml'),
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: { quote_id: quote_id },
                    cache: false
                }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (data.success.length) {
                        alert(data.success);
                    } else {
                        alert('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I am not sure where the issue is. I have checked jQuery UI Dialog and jQuery $.ajax docs several times and my code seems to be right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally and thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071290/719427) I figure it out where the problem was coming from.

First thing, because of this:

```
var quote_id = $('#comment_quote_id')
```

the value of `quote_id` was the whole HTML on not a value as I expected to be.

Second, I was assigning a value to `$('#comment_quote_id')` right here:

```
quote_id.val($(this).data('id'));
```

which is correct.

Third, again my mistake was to use `quote_id` here:

```
data: { quote_id: quote_id }
```

which is - again - wrong because is the whole HTML and not the value itself.

The solution, use `quote_id.val()` Ex:

```
data: { quote_id: quote_id.val() }
```

I can't use `processData: false` because I don't want to pass the HTML but the value.