# Problem uploading image to local folder with node and Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm struggling uploading an image to a local folder using Node and Multer.
The response i get it's successfully, but the image don't save in the folder.
I have already lost a week trying to fix it

And yes, i have checked the destination route, in case you wonder.

This is my frontend:

```
<form id="tasasImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="file"> <br> 
  <div id="uploadImg" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</div>
</form>

<script>
 $("#uploadImg").click(function () {
    if ($('#photo').val().length > 0) {
      var formData = new FormData($('#tasasImage')[0]);
      console.log([...formData])
      $.ajax({
          url: "",
          data: formData,
          type: "POST",
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function(r){
            console.log('Uploaded successfully');
            $("#photo").val('');
          },
          error: function (e) {   
            console.log("some error", e);
          }
      });
  }
 </script>
```

And the backend:

```
var storageTasas = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
       callback(null, config.urlBase+'public/images/tasas');
  },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
       var name = now+'-'+file.originalname;
       callback(null, name);
  }
})

var uploadTasas = multer({ storage: storageTasas }).single('photo'); 

const tasasUploadImage = (req, res) => {
    uploadTasas(req, res, (err) => {
       if (err) { console.error(err); } 
       else {console.log('Ssuccessfully Uploaded') };
    })
    res.send({'file': now});
}

router.post('/admin/aliados/tasas/:id', adminController.tasasUploadImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The url you are passing empty in the JQuery / Client script, it should be url : /admin/aliados/tasas/1234
2. The form data should be like this
   var formData = new FormData($('#tasasImage'));

[simple multipart file upload with express.js and multer with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131569/simple-multipart-file-upload-with-express-js-and-multer-with-ajax)