# $().load gives Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to filter database rows with checkboxes using jQuery.

```js
var $sizeCheckboxes = $("#size input:checkbox");
$sizeCheckboxes.on("change", function() {
  var sizes = getSizes();
  console.log('Size adjusted: ' + sizes);
  $('#products').load("includes/products.php", {
      'pagetitle': pagetitle,
      'category': category,
      'subcategory': subcategory,
      'amount': amount,
      'size': sizes
    },
    function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#products').fadeIn();
        $('.loader').hide();
      }, 500);
    }
  );
});

function getSizes() {
  var sizes = [];
  $sizeCheckboxes.each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      sizes.push(this.value);
    }
  });
  return sizes;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I check the checkboxes for different sizes, it should send this array to my products.php file. (The other values that are being passed via ajax are previously defined)

Now when I check the different sizes, it correctly pushes them to the array (I can see in the console), but I always get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: What is that code without the php intermingled with it?

Comment: Hi Kevin, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: In other words, in your code above, place the php output in place of the php tags. Prove that the problem isn't php. If it is php, you haven't provided enough information to begin working on this.

Comment: The ones you edited out.

Comment: Not quite sure but passing array `sizes` can cause this. Try to `join` sizes array and add a joined string to load's data.

Comment: array sizes should be fine, $.param can handle it.

Comment: I removed the single PHP tag in my code. I am absolutely certain the load script works, since I use similar ones on this page for different input selectors. The problem is with the array `sizes` that I am trying to pass I think.

Comment: You could be right, not sure if `sizes` causes the problem or something else

Comment: run `$.param({foo: [1,2,3]})` in your console, it works fine. the array isn't causing the error you are getting.

Comment: Console output: `foo%5B%5D=1&foo%5B%5D=2&foo%5B%5D=3`

Comment: `$('#products').load('<?php echo` would most certainly throw an error if a php parser doesn't run on it. If it does, then the output from the php very well could be invalid too. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: actually... there's another possibility. This error can be caused by passing a DOM element into $.param, which in your case would mean you're passing a dom element into your $.load data. sizes clearly isn't a dom element, but you didn't show how the rest of the data is obtained. If this is the case, then your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071100/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-at-ajax-request-when-data-param

Comment: Thanks for the help Kevin, I figured out the problem. The problem was caused by the `amount` variable that was only assigned in another function. Thanks for the help.