# Ajax function not working inside If condition in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am sending values from ajax to laravel controller. Following is the jQuery code I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.payment').on('click',function(){
        var paymentName = $('#payment_option').find(":selected").val();
        if(paymentName==''){
            alert("Please select Payment Option");
        }else{
            var count = "{{ $error_count }}";
                if (count<1) {
                    $('#shopping_bag_form').submit();
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: '/user/payment_option',
                            cache: false,
                            data: { payment_option:payment_option },
                            success: function (response) {
                        },
                            error: function (response) {
                        }
                    });
                } else{
                    swal({
                      title: "Please remove unavailable product from the cart",
                      icon: "error",
                      dangerMode: true,
                      buttons: "Ok",
                    }).then((ok) => {
                        return false;
                    })
                }

        }

    });
</script>
```

But the thing is it is not working. I want this send this value once the form is submitted that is why I am using it in `If` condition where I am submitting form. How to make this ajax work.

Below is the error I am receiving in console:-

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
at qt (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.k.param (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (shopping-bag:1077)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Following is the html code:-

```
<label for="delivery_option" class="prod-head size-head"><b>Select Delivery Option:</b></label>

                        <select id="payment_option" name="payment_option">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                          <option value="A">Pick up product from pick up center</option>
                          <option value="B">Ship to my address</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay

Comment: Where is the variable `payment_option` you're trying to send defined? You have a `paymentName` though. Are you using the wrong variable?

Comment: @NicoHaase. I have commented the above form submit code, maybe after that it is not working because the ajax url was not showing up in console. Also, i try to change the name in data as I have used same name for both key and value.

Comment: What do you mean by "commented"? Have you even checked which of these lines throws that error?

Comment: You also have `$('#shopping_bag_form').submit();` right before the ajax request. How is that handled? Is it just submitting the form in an "old-school"-way (reloading the page) or is there some JS getting triggered? If there is JS triggered, are you sure that's not what's causing the issue? If there's no JS, then that call would redirect the client, stopping the JS after from being executed.

Comment: You can isolate your ajax function to see if it works on its own. And not sure if you're using twig or not but in twig you need to remove the $ in the variable. var count = "{{ error_count }}";

Comment: @LeMeme Considering it's Laravel, it's probably Blade syntax, so `{{ $error_count }}` is correct for echoing out a PHP variable.

Comment: Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071367/2516718). The problem is you're passing Html element for the dropdown instead of its value. Replace `payment_option` by `paymentName` (e.g. `data: { payment_option: paymentName }`). By default the browser creates a variable with the id of html elements.