# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation when trying to send a JSON object of data included files

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to send a POST request to the server. The request body is a JSON object contains some objects, texts, files and arrays.

But jQuery returns an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation".

I googled about this situation and I applied some solutions like sending the object inside an array ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071100/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-at-ajax-request-several-eleme)) but it didn't work for me.

Here's my JSON data that I want to send:

[image]

The JS code is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'send.php',
  data: {
    'bbody': lastBody
  },
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(res) {
    if (res == 'success') {
      alert('success');
    }
  }
});
```

`lastBody` is the JSON object.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a text format like CSV. `lastBody` is just a JavaScript object. Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(lastBody, null, 2))` and paste an example of the output here *as text*, not as an image of text. If that command fails, you know what the problem is; that's what jQuery is doing behind the scenes when passing your data to ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `data` has to be a string.
`data: JSON.stringify({key: “value”, key2:”value3”})`