# Illegal invocation while sending formdata to PHP server using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I execute the code I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

How do I fix this?

```js
const formdata = new FormData();
for (const file of myfile.files) {
  formdata.append("myFiles[]", file);
}

$.ajax({
  url: '/all_backend_stuff/server.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    "file": formdata
  },
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  },
  complete: function() {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myFiles[]" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery: 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' at ajax request - several elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071100/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-at-ajax-request-several-eleme)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini not quite - that's a different issue

Answer (score 0):

When sending `FormData` in a jQuery AJAX request you need to supply the object directly to the `data` property (not as the value of a property within an object).

In addition you need to set both `contentType` and `processData` to `false`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/all_backend_stuff/server.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formdata,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  },
  complete: function() {}
});
```

Comment: How do I fetch this data in my PHP script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908250/519413

Comment: I tried `var_dump($_FILES['myFiles']['name']);` but I keep getting an empty response